# Shorten an edge between nodes to absolut length

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

How can I draw only a part of an edge/arrow (of a defined absolut length) between nodes; something like the following but `shorten` always has to be adapted to the distance between `A` and `B` what is difficult and cumbersome:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  %% --- start tikz ---
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    % create two nodes
    \node[draw=black,circle] (A) at (0,0) {A}; 
    \node[draw=black,circle] (B) at (3,4) {B};
    % create arrow starting at A with direction A->B and length 1cm
    % ... I know the shorten option, however; this is not want I want!
    \draw[->,shorten >=3.5cm,shorten <=0cm] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %% --- end tikz ---
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a distance modifier

```
($(A)!1cm!(B)$)
```

This needs `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  %% --- start tikz ---
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    % create two nodes
    \node[draw=black,circle] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw=black,circle] (B) at (3,4) {B};
    % create arrow starting at A with direction A->B and length 1cm
    %    ... I know the shorten option, however; this is not want I want!
    \draw[->] (A) -- ($(A)!1cm!(B)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %% --- end tikz ---
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow - that is an incredible solution! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

This is a possible solution where `intersection` point of unit circle (with name path=curve) and line A-B (with name path=line) is found. However, the red arrow of 2cm is used for demonstration. One may change the macro `\dist` value for other possibilities.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections,calc}

\def\dist{2cm} % the length should be less than the node distance, also note that a node has size.

\begin{document}
 %% --- start tikz ---
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
% create two nodes
\node[draw=black,circle] (A) at (0,0) {A}; 
\node[draw=black,circle] (B) at (3,4) {B};
% create arrow starting at A with direction A->B and length 1cm
% ... I know the shorten option, however; this is not what I want! 
\path[name path=line]  (A)--(B); 
\path[name path=curve] (A)--+(\dist,0) arc (0:90:\dist);  % change \path to \draw see the arc intersection.
\draw[->,shorten >=3.5cm,shorten <=0cm] (A) -- (B);  % OP's code
\draw[name intersections= {of=curve and line, by={a}}, red,->,thick] (A) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
%% --- end tikz ---
\end{document}
```